# ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory inf fedora 20

Tags: mongodb, fedora

MongoDB is not starting.
I have installed mongo and mongo was running but after reboot it is not running.

> ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory

My system is Fedora 20

Its log archive.

```
2014-09-18T00:28:58.515-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3048 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=localhost.localdomain
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build7.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-09-18T00:28:58.522-0300 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1" }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2014-09-18T00:28:58.591-0300 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
2014-09-18T00:28:58.600-0300 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-09-18T00:28:58.961-0300 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-09-18T00:29:06.450-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55047 #1 (1 connection now open)
2014-09-18T00:29:18.402-0300 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:55047 (0 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:29:47.336-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55049 #2 (1 connection now open)
2014-09-18T00:29:47.355-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55050 #3 (2 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:29:58.915-0300 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:54 virt:604
2014-09-18T00:29:58.915-0300 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2014-09-18T00:29:58.915-0300 [clientcursormon]  connections:2
2014-09-18T00:29:59.095-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55055 #4 (3 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:03.065-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55071 #5 (4 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:14.503-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55082 #6 (5 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:27.781-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55093 #7 (6 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:34.899-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55100 #8 (7 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:42.071-0300 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55114 #9 (8 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:52.297-0300 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:55050 (7 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:30:52.299-0300 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:55049 (6 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.252-0300 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:55071 (5 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.255-0300 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:55082 (4 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.256-0300 [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:55093 (3 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.256-0300 [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:55114 (2 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.259-0300 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:55055 (1 connection now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:01.277-0300 [conn8] end connection 127.0.0.1:55100 (0 connections now open)
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: 
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 8
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
2014-09-18T00:31:02.252-0300 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2014-09-18T00:31:02.253-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.253-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.253-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.253-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.253-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.508-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.509-0300 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-09-18T00:31:02.509-0300 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2014-09-18T00:31:02.509-0300 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2014-09-18T00:31:03.069-0300 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-09-18T00:31:03.069-0300 [signalProcessingThread] dbexit: really exiting now
2014-09-18T00:31:49.408-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:31:49.457-0300 ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
2014-09-18T00:34:39.353-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:34:39.356-0300 ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
2014-09-18T00:37:04.978-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:37:04.983-0300 ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
2014-09-18T00:40:37.708-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:40:37.713-0300 ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
2014-09-18T00:50:07.490-0300 ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2014-09-18T00:50:07.494-0300 ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 17):

What worked for me in Ubuntu is a combination of the answers from @Tuan Nguyen and @Tom Carchrae

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:27017) 
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
sudo rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo mkdir -p  /var/run/mongodb/
touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

You can then run

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: For those that find this, when you chown, the user account is most likely "mongod" instead of "mongodb" now... FYI.

Answer (score 6):

The MongoDB packages contain a "bug" which prevents them from starting properly on the newer RedHat based systems. Please see [SERVER-14679](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14679) for details.

As a workaround until 2.6.5 is released, please edit the init script according to https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/50ca596ace0b1390482408f1b19ffb1f9170cab6

Answer (score 6):

i finally found a solution that worked for me (I'm using Ubuntu on my Vagrant VM), i started with this :

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb/
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb
```

But when i checked my logs with :

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

I still had this :

> [HOUR] I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
>
> [HOUR] I CONTROL  [main] ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongod.pid: Permission denied

So i've edited a file named mongod.pid with nothing in it :

```
sudo vim /var/run/mongod.pid
```

And i've changed the rights :

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb mongod.pid
```

Final folders, users & rights :

> drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb  mongodb    40 Jul 27 09:28 mongodb/
>
> -rw-r--r--  1 mongodb  mongodb     1 Jul 27 09:35 mongod.pid

Then :

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

And that finally worked :)

Comment: I did similar. "tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log " and resolved the indicated permissions errors. There were a couple.  using CentOS

Answer (score 3):

This helped me to go ahead

```
mkdir -p  /var/run/mongodb/ ;chown -R  mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb/
```

Comment: on ubuntu the user is mongodb, so `mkdir -p  /var/run/mongodb/ ;chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb`

Answer (score 3):

step by step, centos 6.8

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:27017) 
rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
rm -f /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 
rm -f /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid 
sudo service mongod start
```

open port 27017 and save changes

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
sudo service iptables sav
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. The files in /var/run are not persistent.
2. The `mongodb` user does not have the privilege to write to /var/run

Solution:

Use [`systemd-tmpfiles`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html) to create the directory `/var/run/mongodb` on every startup.

1. Create a file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mongodb.conf`.
2. Add the following in the file.

   `d /var/run/mongodb 2775 mongodb mongodb - -`

Answer (score 0):

Also tried the same of the first above, which worked before but on another server it didn't, strange, anyway what worked finally was:
(Running Ubuntu server)

```
# mkdir /var/run/mongodb/
# touch /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# chown -hR mongodb /var/run/mongodb/
# chown mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# service mongod restart
# service mongod status
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers that mention doing `sudo chown -R  mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb/` worked for me at first but then fail on reboot on Ubuntu since those files get recreated at every boot.

The solution is to create this file:

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mongod.conf
```

And populate it like this:

```
d /run/mongod 0755 mongodb mongodb -
```

The above path may vary between distros but the idea is to have the system auto-generate the needed directory instead of trying to create it manually. In my case (running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS), the path is specified in:

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

In this block:

```
# how the process runs
processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid
```

You may see a slightly different path in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` but it's `mongod.conf` overrides it.