# Mongodb crash got signal 15 (Terminated)

Tags: mongodb, crash

my mongodb server suddenly got signal 15 (Terminated). I don't have any idea why the mongodb crashed. Below is the log messages.

```
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.701 [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 dbexit: 
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 9
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 10
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.704 [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 11
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.705 [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.705 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.705 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.706 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.706 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Mon Jun 27 07:33:31.706 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
```

Below is restart process.

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=888 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=jasa-online
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] build info: Linux orlo 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_54
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.500 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "0.0.0.0", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.531 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Mon Jun 27 07:34:22.531 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
```

The MongoDB shell version is 2.4.9. How can i figured out why this is happen ? Is that caused by long running query that run more than 300s ?

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out? Just ran into the same issue today

Comment: No, i did not.
I resolve this issue by remove the mongo server to another mongo only server.
I think mongo get no resource left and may be some long running query hang in there.
I am still curious why this is happened btw.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I was running into the issue and stumbled across this question.  I managed to solve it.

My issue was on Ubuntu 18.04 and attempting to install and run MongoDB 3.4/3.6.

One issue was a missing /var/run/mongodb directory with the appropriate permissions, the other was this error.  I'm still not 100% sure if this error was related to the directory or not, but it definitely had something to do with the configs.

My mongod.conf ended up having processManagement - fork set to true.  Changing that to false allowed it to start working.

Comment: based on your advice I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755924/3904109 but even after creating the directories it fails after some time, is there a timeout or limit to number of documents

Comment: changing processManagement to false did the trick for me. It was running as a service and the forking was causing init to terminate the forked child process

Comment: "My mongod.conf ended up having processManagement - fork set to true. Changing that to false allowed it to start working." worked for me too.

Comment: Where is the `mongod.config` file located?

Comment: in ubuntu `/etc/mongod.conf` - see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem after including the PID file path in mongod.conf.

It was like this:

```
processManagement:
   timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
   fork: true
   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

In my case, I had put "fork: true", but I hadn't included the PID file path.

Comment: i don't think you need fork if that's started as a service

Answer (score 0):

make sure path confing in /usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
and /etc/mongod.conf the same

Comment: can you please elaborate I am having this problem on MongoDb v4.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've literally seen this fixed today by editing the `mongod.conf` file (in my Mac it resides at `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`), and replacing this:

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true
```

with this:

```
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

If are you using MongoDB version below 3.0, Please upgrade to 3.2 or latest version.

[image: MongoDB Bug]

Refer: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24282

Comment: does not help, mongo version shouldn't matter.