# ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid: Unknown error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

**Stack information** :

**BE** : NodeJS App, MongoDB

**FE** : AngularJS App

**Use case :**
I am deploying BE(NodeJS) application on AWS ECS along with MongoDB. There is a task definition (AWS) in which there should be both the containers attached so that Mongo container can be linked to the NodeJS container. Mongo container is from docker hub registry **registry.hub.docker.com/library/mongo:latest**

Please note I have also subscribed to the CloudWatch Logs for the containers.

I am also providing the MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD & MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME as new user environment variables.

**Problem :**
As soon as the service bootstraps NodeJS container, it gets failed with below error.

2019-05-28T14:15:23.208+0000 I CONTROL [main] ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid: Unknown error

[image]

**Result** :
As a result, mongo is not able to get started and NodeJS app is unable to operate on the db. I want this db operations within container (ECS) as a solution.

Please guide what I am doing wrong here!! Kindly Help!

**Why it differs from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903980/error-cannot-write-pid-file-to-var-run-mongodb-mongod-pid-no-such-file-or-dir) answer/question :**
Because in my case the application along with MongoDB is running in container environment and container (Node container) is all responsible for bootstrapping it or restarting the mongo service. Also, the error I am facing is *Unknown Error*.

**EDIT :**
Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:8-alpine

    # Create app directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    # Install app dependencies
    # A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
    # where available (npm@5+)

    COPY package*.json ./


    RUN npm install
    # RUN npm audit

    # Bundle app source
    #COPY . /usr/src/app

    COPY . .

    EXPOSE 9000
    CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory inf fedora 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903980/error-cannot-write-pid-file-to-var-run-mongodb-mongod-pid-no-such-file-or-dir)

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam My concern is different why because in my case the application along with MongoDB is running in container environment and container (Node container) is all responsible for bootstrapping it or restarting the mongo service.

Comment: can you show your dockerfile

Comment: @Adiii Please review the added docker file content.

Comment: @Kuldeep MongoDB please where u facing issue

Comment: @Adiii As I mentioned in the question content, I am using MongoDB image from Docker hub registry. registry.hub.docker.com/library/mongo:latest. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: I run the same image working in ECS with , try to run standalone then use linking.