# /var/run/mongodb/ folder is deleted every system reboot

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

Every time I restart the system the "/var/run/mongodb/" folder is deleted and mongodb cannot be started. Here is my mongod.conf file:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 38512
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.


security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/lib/mongodb/replica_set_key

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: "dbr"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I first tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54755924/14971470 for the

```
"ERROR: Cannot write pid file to {path_string}: {errAndStr_second}","attr":{"path_string":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","errAndStr_second":"No such file or directory""
```

error and it fixed it.
But every time I restart the system, the "/var/run/mongodb/" folder is deleted again and mongodb can't be started.

Comment: This is an operating system question, not a programming question.  See https://serverfault.com/questions/74796/directory-in-var-run-gets-deleted-after-hard-reboot

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, the directories inside /var/run/ get deleted upon reboot. If it's okay to create the /var/run/mongodb directory when the mongod service starts, you can add the following content to the mongod.service file:

$ sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

What worked for me was to comment out the  pidFilePath: then `systemctl enable mongod` then `systemctl start mongod`